# How to arrange buttons in JFrame in java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I'm just beginner at programming. I want to write a calculator in NetBeans IDE (just its graphic). But I have some problem in putting button in the way I want.
two buttons have a different size (0  &  = button). But I don't know how to put them!

and here is my code :

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   JPanel[] row = new JPanel[7];
   JButton[] button = new JButton[28];
   String[] buttonString = {"MC", "MR", "MS", "M+", "M-",
                            "CL", "CE", "C", "+/-",  "√",
                            "7", "8", "9", "/", "%",
                            "4", "5", "6", "*", "1/x",
                            "1", "2", "3", "-",
                            ".", "+", "0", "="};

   Dimension displayDimension = new Dimension( 275, 60);
   Dimension regularDimension = new Dimension( 55 , 40);
   Dimension zeroButDimension = new Dimension( 110 , 40);
   Dimension equalButDimension = new Dimension( 55 , 80);

   JTextArea display = new JTextArea(1,20);
   Font font = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);

   Calculator() {   
       super("CALC"); 
       setDesign();
       setSize(300, 350);
       setResizable(false);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(7,5);  
       setLayout(grid);
       FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER); 
       FlowLayout f2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,1,1);
       for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
          row[i] = new JPanel();
       row[0].setLayout(f1);
       for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
          row[i].setLayout(f2);
       for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
          button[i] = new JButton();
          button[i].setText(buttonString[i]);
          button[i].setFont(font);
          button[i].addActionListener(this);
       }
       display.setFont(font);
       display.setEditable(false);
       display.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
       display.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);
       for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
          button[i].setPreferredSize(regularDimension);
       button[26].setPreferredSize(equalButDimension);
       button[24].setPreferredSize(regularDimension);
       button[25].setPreferredSize(regularDimension);
       button[27].setPreferredSize(zeroButDimension);

       row[0].add(display); 
       add(row[0]);

       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          row[1].add(button[i]);
       add(row[1]);

       for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
          row[2].add(button[i]);
       add(row[2]);

       for(int i = 10; i < 15; i++)    
          row[3].add(button[i]);
       add(row[3]); 

       for(int i = 15; i < 20; i++)    
          row[4].add(button[i]);
       add(row[4]); 

       for(int i = 20; i < 24; i++)    
          row[5].add(button[i]);
       row[5].add(button[26]);
       add(row[5]);

       row[6].add(button[27]);
       row[6].add(button[24]);
       row[6].add(button[25]);
       add(row[6]);

       setVisible(true); 
    }

    public final void setDesign() {
       try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
       }  catch(Exception e) {  
    }
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

  }

   public static void main(String[] arguments) {
      Calculator c = new Calculator();
  }
}
```

What should I do to arrange them correctly?

Comment: You should experiment with different types of layout managers. These do most of that work for you. For a calculator, being a series of rows and columns, I would think a GridBagLayout would probably work rather nicely. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: What is `arrange them correctly`? Iv'e seen calculators with many button arrangements.

Comment: if you run that you'll understand what I mean:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the gridbaglayout. It allows you to place elements (buttons, text fields, etc) based on a grid. Here is the documentation for it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

I also recommend looking at some of the other layout managers, as there are some very interesting and useful ones out there. For a general introduction to GUI layouts, see the documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

The above link has all the information you'll need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use eclipse window builder or something? You can simply resize the buttons graphically. Doing all swing programming yourself is a waste of time, your much better off using a gui to build your gui editor and focus more on sorting your business logic. If you wanna do someone really specific with swing you can spend time studying it more thoroughly.

But if you just wanna resize certain buttons you can use buttons setPreferredSize methods instead of the setSize ones.

Comment: I disagree. WindowBuilder tends to have a lot of glitches and it uses older methods to create the layouts and everything. It is not reliable. When I used it I had to go back through and make manual changes to everything WindowBuilder did for me, so it did not save me any time at all.

Comment: Fixing the few errors you need to fix in windowbuilder takes a lot lesser time than doing everything manually in my opinion but I suppose it's a matter of taste.

Comment: As I mentioned it actually takes longer to go through all the code and fix all the messed up parts that WB did. Also, another issue with WindowBuilder that I did not mention is that it is very touchy--if you adjust the way its code is set up even slightly, it will no longer display the graphical representation, even if the code is perfectly fine. I grew very tired of that issue and started coding by hand because of it. WindowBuilder really cannot be trusted.

Comment: It's not really one way or the other it's a matter of opinion, you prefer it your way I the other. As I said it's a matter of preference.

Comment: I suppose we can agree that for simpler projects it may work (though still not have optimal code right from the get-go) but for larger projects (what I'm used to) it may not be a good choice? I am guessing that's where our experiences differ. I was working on a full-size program that used quite a few windows, so going through the code for that and fixing things was a fair amount of work